# Java division loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20.

I've started by creating a for loop to run from numbers 1 to 20, then I know I have to create another loop that divides a certain number by every number between 1 and 20, if the modulus of these two numbers is not 0, then skip to the next number (i.e. increment by 1) until I find the smallest number.

```
public class Problem5 {

 public static void main(String args[]){

    for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
        for(int counter=1;variable length argument?;counter++){

        if(i%counter==0){ 

            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

I know that I need a second for loop to count from 1 to whatever number I need, so do I need a variable length argument as I don't know what the smallest number is?

Comment: Tip: Most P.E. is not about simple brute-force; many problems are infeasible to solve trying such.

Answer (score 1):

You need the loops the other way around and you don't need to check for `% 1`  can sastertart with the highest prime number if you like. If it's a multiple for 4 and 5, it must be a multiple of 20 as well ;)

Since it has to be a multiple of all the primes you only need to check multiples of 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19.  This will make it much, much faster.

There is no upper limit so you don't need to add one.  You can make it `counter < Integer.MAX_VALUE` if you like.

---

Instead of using brute force you can calculate what the factors must be.

```
public class CommonMultipleMain {
    static final int MAX = Integer.getInteger("max", 1000);

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        // warmup
        getLowestMultipleOf(60);

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        BigInteger bi = getLowestMultipleOf(MAX);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Smallest number which has factors up to " + MAX + " took " + time / 1000 + " us, is " + bi);
    }

    private static BigInteger getLowestMultipleOf(int max) {
        int[] maxFactorCount = new int[max + 1];
        for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
            int[] factors = getFactorsFor(i);
            for (int j = 2; j < factors.length; j++)
                if (maxFactorCount[j] < factors[j])
                    maxFactorCount[j] = factors[j];
        }
        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(maxFactorCount[2]);
        for (int i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) {
            int exponent = maxFactorCount[i];
            switch (exponent) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                    break;
                default:
                    bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i).pow(exponent));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return bi;
    }

    private static int[] getFactorsFor(int i) {
        int[] factors = new int[i + 1];
        while ((i & 1) == 0) {
            i >>= 1;
            factors[2]++;
        }
        for (int j = 3; j * j <= i; j += 2) {
            while (i % j == 0) {
                i /= j;
                factors[j]++;
            }
        }
        if (i > 1)
            factors[i]++;
        return factors;
    }
}
```

prints

Smallest number which has factors up to 1000 took 15005 us, is 7128865274665093053166384155714272920668358861885893040452001991154324087581111499476444151913871586911717817019575256512980264067621009251465871004305131072686268143200196609974862745937188343705015434452523739745298963145674982128236956232823794011068809262317708861979540791247754558049326475737829923352751796735248042463638051137034331214781746850878453485678021888075373249921995672056932029099390891687487672697950931603520000

It would take longer than the age of the universe to count up to this number, but by calculating it, it takes less time than it takes to blink.

Comment: Do you think that pre-computing all of the prime numbers between 2 an the given number and using only them to get the factors (also mapping the factors array by the prime number array indexes) will make it even faster?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easily calculated without brute-force iterating over all integers until you find the answer:

```
Num Factors
 2    2
 3    3
 4    2 already have one '2', need only one more
 5    5
 6      already have 2 & 3
 7    7
 8    2 already have 2 '2's, need only one more
 9    3 already have one '3', need only one more
10      already have 2 and 5
11   11
12      already have 2 '2's and a '3'
13   13
14      etc...
15   
16    2
17   17
18    
19   19
20
```

Multiply together all the numbers in the second column.  Implementation in Java is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
int eulersmallestNumber(int value){
    int start = 1; 
    boolean found = false;
    while(!found){
        found = eulerhelper(start,value); 
        start++;
    } 
    return start;
}

boolean eulerhelper(int start, int value){
    for(int i=1;i<=value;i++){
        if(i%start != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You give `eulersmallestNumber` a max number you want it to loop through for instance 10.

It will solve this problem.

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers
>   from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

How it works.

It increments from the starting value of 1 and calls the function eulerhelper which returns a boolean.
(while loop will exit once eulerhelper returns true)

eulerhelper gets the value and divides through all the values `1 - value`. If one of those values has a reminder it returns false. However, if all the values between those numbers have no reminder it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Starting by your approach, you will need to go until i/2 (or ideally sqrt(i)). So we will get (we skip ones):

(edited: revised and corrected code)

```
int i,j,mult;
int smallest = 2; // Start with 2
for (i = 3; i <= 20; i++)
{
    if (smallest % i == 0) // Already divisible
        continue;

    mult = i;
    // We try to divide every number from 2 to 20 with
    // the numbers before it, so that we skip repeating
    // prime factors and get the smallest numbers
    for (j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
    {
        // j too high
        if (mult / j == 0) 
            break;

        if (mult % j == 0)
            mult /= j;
    }

    // mult will be 1 if the current number is a product
    // of 2 or more numbers before it
    smallest *= mult;
}

printf("%d\n", smallest);
```

It's C, but you should understand it just fine. For checking, take all the numbers from 1 to 20 and write their prime factorization. Then take all the primes at the highest power and multiply them. It should be 232792560